# Two different methods for clustering (by spectral analysis) and two different results... what's hapenning?

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am annoyed because I used (what it has to be) two equivalent methods.
My aim is to cluster a graph into different groups. For that, on the one side I do it "by hand", computing the fiedler :

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy.linalg as la

g1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A.values )
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(g1)
D = np.diag(np.ravel(np.sum(A,axis=1)))
L=D-A

l, U = la.eigh(L)
# fiedler
f = U[:,1]
labels = np.ravel(np.sign(f))
coord = nx.spring_layout(g1, iterations=100,seed=42)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g1, coord, node_size=25, node_color=labels, cmap = 'cool')


coord = nx.spectral_layout(g1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g1, coord, node_size=25, node_color=labels, cmap = 'cool')
```

I get this really convincing spectral representation : 
[image]

Now, using this bit of code (in a more systematic way):

```
import networkx as nx
import sklearn
clustering = sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
                                                assign_labels="discretize",
                                                random_state=0)
clustering = clustering.fit(A) 
labels = clustering.labels_ 
coord = nx.spring_layout(g1, iterations=100,seed=42)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g1, coord,node_size=25,node_color=labels, cmap = 'cool')
```

I get a really bad result, which doesn't look the same at all.

So my question is, why ? Could one explain to me how on earth I get different results ?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you invoke sklearn's spectral clustering, **you use the RBF kernel interpreting your affinity matrix as coordinates**. I'm not surprised that this does not work well.

Wrong input -> wrong output.

Try `affinity='precomputed'`.

Comment: do you mind explaining what affinity do ? please. How does it impact the results

Comment: I am asking because the results are still different. The idea is there (one of the branch is the cluster), but it still lacks a few points. And since I want to cluster in more than 2 groups, I need to be sure that the two methods agree.

Comment: See the documentation and theory of spectral clustering. It uses an affinity. A reasonable default is to compute this using rbf kernels from data. It's also pretty much guaranteed that the results will be different, because it involves random... Run it twice in sklearn and you'll likely get two different results.

Comment: Can you confirm me then that my first method is better ? However for multi clustering, the second is mandatory?

Comment: I am sorry but I know the theory, and still your answer improve the similarity between the two but does not solve the problem. Whatsoever random stat I am stating, I still get the same different result!

Comment: I don't use spectral clustering. You have the source of sklearn, so you can check what they are doing. There are at least *three* different laplacians you can use, for efficiency you'll want to approximate the eigenvectors, you can vary the number of vectors in the embedding, and then the actual clustering... Too many variables.